# How to put a ContextMenu into the header of a TabPage

Tags: c#, events, contextmenu, tabcontrol

I have a custom `TabControl` in which I have `TabPages` with `ContextMenu` bound to them.

I want the menu to show up only when the page header is being clicked.

What I do is that, when the `TabControl` is clicked, I check these conditions:

```
private void MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Button == Mousebuttons.Right) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < TabCount; ++i) 
        {
            Rectangle r = GetTabRect(i);
            if (r.Contains(e.Location) /* && it is the header that was clicked*/) 
            {
                // Change slected index, get the page, create contextual menu
                ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
                // Add several items to menu
                page.ContextMenu = cm;
                page.ContextMenu.Show(this, e.Location);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**If I bind `MouseUp` to the  `TabControl`, I get the  `ContextMenu` in the entire  `TabPage`. If I bind it to the  `TabPage`, I only get the  `ContextMenu` in the body and not in the header.**

Is there a way to have a ContextMenu to show up only on header Click ?

Comment: Is that `MouseUp` event wired to every `TabPage`, or to the `TabControl`?

Comment: The MouseUp is wired to the TabControl. If I Wire it to the TabControl I get the ContextMenu in the entire tabpage. If I bind it to the TabPage I only get the ContextMenu in the body and not in the header.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just don't ever assign the ContextMenu to anything...simply display it:

```
public class MyTabControl : TabControl
{

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < TabCount; ++i)
            {
                Rectangle r = GetTabRect(i);
                if (r.Contains(e.Location) /* && it is the header that was clicked*/)
                {
                    // Change slected index, get the page, create contextual menu
                    ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
                    // Add several items to menu
                    cm.MenuItems.Add("hello");
                    cm.MenuItems.Add("world!");
                    cm.Show(this, e.Location);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: just by curiosity, what are the reasons not to assign a ContextMenu to anything ?

Comment: If it's not assigned then it can't appear when you don't want it to.  Since you're creating the menu dynamically at run-time, it doesn't need to be stored anywhere anyways...

Answer (score 4):

Instead of override like Idle_Mind said, you could also do the same with a normal tabcontrol on the mouseevent:

```
    private void tabControl1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabCount; ++i)
            {
                Rectangle r = tabControl1.GetTabRect(i);
                if (r.Contains(e.Location) /* && it is the header that was clicked*/)
                {
                    // Change slected index, get the page, create contextual menu
                    ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
                    // Add several items to menu
                    cm.MenuItems.Add("hello");
                    cm.MenuItems.Add("world!");
                    cm.Show(tabControl1, e.Location);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It does exactly the same, but doesn't add an extra control in your toolbox:)
You could also make it generic if you want to use it on multiple TabControls.

```
    private void showContextMenu_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            TabControl tabControl1 = sender as TabControl;
            [...]
```